Lower bound on cardinality of unions
Suppose you have an uncountable family $X$ of disjoint open sets and $Y$ some dense set. Then I would assume that it automatically follows that $Y$ is uncountable. It intersects every non-empty open set non-trivially, so $Z=\{Y\cap x:x\in X\}$ is an uncountable family of disjoint subsets of $Y$. I would now conclude that since $\bigcup Z\subseteq Y$, so $Y$ is uncountable. Indeed, since every $z\in Z$ is non-empty, I have at least uncountably many distinct elements in the union. A certain person is claiming that I am wrong and that I need axiom of choice to prove that $\bigcup Z$ is uncountable.
Now, I can go for a contradiction and assume $Y$ is countable, then let $f:Y\to\omega$ be some injective function, but then $\{\min f(z):z\in Z\}$ is an uncountable subset of $\omega$. But cannot I get this by the argument above? I already know that there are at least uncountably many distinct elements in it, I would assume I do not need to have a set of them to know they exist.
Or generally speaking, suppose a family $\{X_i\}_{i\in\kappa}$ of cardinality $\kappa$ of pairwise disjoint sets. Can I then, without choice, conclude that $\bigcup_{i\in\kappa}X_i$ has at least cardinality of $\kappa$? Or, restating the question without cardinals, that there is an injective function from $\kappa$ into the union? I know that choice is used to prove upper bounds, but I cannot find anything on lower bounds. I only saw one post, which I cannot find anymore, claiming I can then naturally construct an injection $\kappa\to\bigcup_{i\in\kappa} X_i$, but this natural construction was not shown.

Open sets? In what topology? What space?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@AsafKaragila Yes in topology (in $l^\infty$), but that was just an illutrastion. My question is about cardinality of general unions. That is the first question is, if I can simply conclude uncountability (without going for a contradiction) from the family being an uncountable family of disjoint subsets. The more general question should be understandable.

You are correct in the case of the countable case. Since the open sets are disjoint, you can enumerate $Y$ and pick the least one from each open set. This is essentially how we prove that any family of pairwise disjoint open sets in $\Bbb R$ is countable. But here we are using the fact that $Y$ is dense, the topology is giving us more information. If all you want to talk about is the union of sets, though, we run into problems.
We can have a proper class of sets which have the property:

$X$ is a countable union of finite sets, even of size $2$ if we want that.
$X$ does not have a countably infinite subset.
Given any set-many of these $X$s, there is some $Y$ in our class which has a cardinality different from all of them.

So there is no lower bound on the cardinality here. This can be generalised and made worse. But it shows already that things are breaking down completely.
In fact, we can make those "countable union of finite sets" into almost any kind of "union of finite sets", should we want to.

So to understand you correctly, in generall (in $ZF$ without AC) I cannot assume that there is some injective function from the Indexset $\kappa$ into the union $\bigcup_{i\in\kappa}X_i$?

Nope. Not at all.
